# React and navigating to a selected item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table of user I am displaying to a user. They click a row, and I want to navigate to a component to show the details.

```
  <tbody>
    {this.state.clients.map(client => (
      <tr className="tableRow" onClick={() => this.handleSelection(client.id)}>
        <td>{client.name}</td>
```

My Route is setup like this:

```
<Route path="/client/:clientId" component={Client} />
```

So in the row, I have an onClick event, which calls a function, passing the parameter selected. Here's the function:

```
  handleSelection(clientId) {
    this.props.history.push(`/client/${clientId}`);
  }
```

Then, in the constructor of the target component, I am just logging the selected id, which will be passed to the api to load the data:

```
console.log('Loading clientId...', this.props.match.params.clientId);
```

But this seem wrong. I get the right ID and all, but .. am I doing this right? Is there a better/safer way to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would just be to use individual Link tags inside each TD:

```
<td><Link to={`/client/${client.id}`}>{client.name}</Link></td>
```

That would also be more accessible, since vision impaired users might have trouble triggering that onclick event.

Comment: With this, you need to add it to each ‘td’ right? As adding it around the ‘tr’ causes table issues.

Comment: Yes exactly.  Of course, you could precompute the URL ahead of time, eg. `const to = \`/client/${client.id}\`;` and use that when making your Links: `<td><Link to={to}>{client.name}</Link></td>` , or you could make a function like say `const createLinkedTd = text => <td><Link to={to}>{text}</Link></td>` and then use it instead, eg. `<tr>{createLinkedTd(client.name)}`.  But the core idea is to use one link tag per TD, correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `react-router-dom` it has a `Link` component

```
{this.state.clients.map(client => (
  <Link to={`/client/${clientId}`} >
    <tr className="tableRow">
      <td>{client.name}</td>
  </Link>
```

It's better to use a link rather than an onClick on on a table row for accessibility.
If you're not using `react-router-dom` you can roll your own version from looking at the source - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js

By working in this way it'll behave correctly when people command click on the link to open it in a new tab.

For the routes you grab the params as you have, if you don't want the component to deal with match in the properties you can do something like this:

```
<Route path="/client/:clientId" children={({ match }) => (<Client {...match.params} />)} />
```

Comment: Ah, that's looking way better. And then on the recieving component - how best should I get the clientId from the url?

Comment: I think taking the param out of the props as you're doing is the correct approach.
If you use a render method rather than a component, you can make the components agnostic of `react-dom-router`.

Comment: It seems the Link around the ‘tr’ causes thevtable formatting to fail.